# Syncopation in Greensleeves?

Tags: theory, notation, rhythm, syncopation

Can anyone explain if there's syncopation in Ralph Vaughan Williams' (To sir with love version) of Fantasia on Greensleeves.

Comment: Are you asking about any specific part?

Comment: You might get a more useful answer if you edit to explain why you’re looking for syncopation in it.

Answer (score 4):

There's no syncopation at all in the piece.

Comment: There was an ongoing debate among my musical colleagues in my college (university) days about whether a dotted rhythm counts as syncopation.  The argument was that the short note, because it's not on the beat, meets the definition.  That wasn't my position, so I agree with this answer, but it is worth mentioning that there are people who would disagree with it -- or at least there are four or five people who would have disagreed with it when they were around 20, give or take a couple of years.

Comment: @phoog See https://music.stackexchange.com/q/131773/78419

Comment: @phoog I'm aware that some people consider dotted rhythms to be syncopation. If the poster were asking whether the dotted rhythms were syncopation then the question would be a duplicate: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/131544/syncopation-and-dotted-rhythms?rq=1